# Check these errors

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, compilation-error, preamble

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\centering
\caption{$O_2$ Basis set convergence of the Cartesian anapole susceptibility tensor computed at the UHF level.}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule\toprule
Basis  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{STO-3G}         & -15.451   & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -15.438 & 0           & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -15.451   & $\cdots$  & 0       & -15.438     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.692    & 0       & 0           &-2.692\\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{cc-pVDZ}         & -10.094    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -10.086 & 0           & 0 
                                 & $\cdots$  & -10.094   & $\cdots$  & 0       & -10.086     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.988    & 0       & 0           &-2.692 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{aug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0           & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule                               \
\multirow{3}{*}{aug-cc-pVTZ}    & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925& 0              & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925& 0             & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{LSTO-3G}         & -6.932         & $\cdots$       & $\cdots$      & -6.925     & 0             & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0     & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lcc-pVDZ}        & -6.932   & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$       & -6.925  & 0             & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932  & $\cdots$    & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lcc-pVTZ}        & -6.932   & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$       & -6.925  & 0             & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932  & $\cdots$    & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Laug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932   & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$   & -6.925& 0             & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932  & $\cdots$    & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Laug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932   & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$   & -6.925& 0             & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932  & $\cdots$    & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\bottomrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\caption{$O_2$ Basis set convergence of the Cartesian anapole susceptibility tensor computed at the UHF level.}
\begin{tabular}
\toprule
\toprule
Basis  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{uSTO-3G}         & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{ucc-pVDZ}        & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{ucc-pVTZ}        & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932  & $\cdots$    & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVTZ}    & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{LuSTO-3G}        & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lucc-pVDZ}       & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lucc-pVTZ}       & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVDZ}   & -2.400    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -4.014    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0.484      & -2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVTZ}   & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -6.925  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -6.932    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.386    & 0       & 0.495      &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVQZ}   & -2.053    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.054  & 0          & 0 \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & -3.752    & $\cdots$  & 0       & -3.752     & 0  \\
                                 & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -2.352    & 0       & 0.486      &-2.353 \\
\bottomrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are missing `\\ `  at the end of th previous line, `\multirow{3}{*}{cc-pVDZ}         & -10.094    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -10.086 & 0           & 0 ` should be `\multirow{3}{*}{cc-pVDZ}         & -10.094    & $\cdots$  & $\cdots$  & -10.086 & 0           & 0 \\ `

Comment: Welcome. You need to remove the `\\ ` at the end of your captions for a start and make sure each table row has `\\ ` at the end, some of them do not hence the errors. Adding `\ ` in your package and table options does not make the code compile, not sure if that is OverLeaf or not

Comment: Near the start of the second `minipage`, one finds `\begin{tabular}`. That's bad. I can only guess that you really want is `\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}`.

Comment: Please don't post text as images; it's hard to read and impossible to search.  I would also recommend working your way through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 to create a smaller example.  I would also recommend some explanatory text beyond the title, to give some context to what you're doing.  That would help avoid the down vote that someone else gave you.

Answer (score 3):

The following comments are in no particular order:

- Missing `\\` (line break macro) in data row 2 of the 1st table
- Incomplete `\begin{tabular}` statement at start of 2nd table
- Unsuccessful usage of `minipage` wrappers and `\hfill` directive between the `minipage`/`tabular` environments. Just because you encase a `tabular` environment in a `minipage` of width `\columnwidth` does not guarantee or imply that the width of the `tabular` environment will equal `\columnwidth`.
- There is no way that both tables are going to fit on a single page -- unless you were to employ a tinier-than-`\tiny` font size and made the tables unreadable anyway -- or were to sacrifice a bit of numerical precision in the data columns. Better to place the `tabular` environments into separate `table*` environments.
- Optional improvements:

  - Align the numbers in the six data columns on their decimal markers. This could be done with the machinery of the `siunitx` or `dcolumn` packages.
  - Encase the `\caption` directives and `tabular` environments in `threepartable` environments. This limits the widths of the captions to those of the associated tabular-like environments.
  - Don't double up `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` directives.

The following screenshot shows the start of the first of two tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot]{geometry}
%%%\usepackage{multicol} % not needed

%% new:
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
%%\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{$O_2$ Basis set convergence of the Cartesian anapole susceptibility tensor computed at the UHF level.}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{*{2}{S[table-format=-2.3]}S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}
\toprule
%\toprule
Basis  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} 
       & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{STO-3G}          & -15.451     & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -15.438 & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -15.451     & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -15.438     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.692      & 0       & 0           &-2.692\\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{cc-pVDZ}         & -10.094     & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -10.086 & 0           & 0  \\ %%%%% <-- missing linebreak
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -10.094     & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -10.086     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.988      & 0       & 0           &-2.692 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{aug-cc-pVDZ}     & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule                               \
\multirow{3}{*}{aug-cc-pVTZ}     & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925& 0             & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{LSTO-3G}         & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lcc-pVDZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lcc-pVTZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Laug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Laug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\bottomrule
%%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
%%\end{minipage}
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}
\centering
%%\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{$O_2$ Basis set convergence of the Cartesian anapole susceptibility tensor computed at the UHF level.}
%% \begin{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}
\toprule
%%\toprule
Basis  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} 
       & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\midrule % not \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{uSTO-3G}         & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{ucc-pVDZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{ucc-pVTZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVTZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{LuSTO-3G}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lucc-pVDZ}       & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lucc-pVTZ}       & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVDZ}   & -2.400      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -4.014      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0.484      & -2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVTZ}   & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0.495      &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVQZ}   & -2.053      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.054  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -3.752      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -3.752     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.352      & 0       & 0.486      &-2.353 \\
\bottomrule
%%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
%%\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you're willing to round the numbers in all data columns so that they show 2 rather 3 decimal digits, it turns out that it is just -- but only just -- possible to fit both tables next to each other, thanks to the very narrow page margins you have specified. Incidentally, since you're using a `table*` environment and the overall available width equals `\textwidth`, I'd express the widths of the `minipage` environments as fractions of `\textwidth`, not `\columnwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=1cm,includefoot]{geometry}
%%%\usepackage{multicol} % not needed

%% new:
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. whitespace
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2} % enable automatic rounding
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.485\textwidth}
\caption{$O_2$ Basis set convergence of the Cartesian anapole susceptibility tensor computed at the UHF level.}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{6}{S[table-format=-1.2]} }
\toprule
%\toprule
Basis  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} 
       & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{STO-3G}          & -15.451     & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -15.438 & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -15.451     & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -15.438     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.692      & 0       & 0           &-2.692\\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{cc-pVDZ}         & -10.094     & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -10.086 & 0           & 0  \\ %%%%% <-- missing linebreak
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -10.094     & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -10.086     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.988      & 0       & 0           &-2.692 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{aug-cc-pVDZ}     & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule                               \
\multirow{3}{*}{aug-cc-pVTZ}     & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925& 0             & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{LSTO-3G}         & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lcc-pVDZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lcc-pVTZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Laug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Laug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0           & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925      & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0           &-2.386 \\
\bottomrule
%%\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.485\textwidth}
\caption{$O_2$ Basis set convergence of the Cartesian anapole susceptibility tensor computed at the UHF level.}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{6}{S[table-format=-1.2]} }
\toprule
Basis  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{A}$} 
       & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\midrule % not \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{uSTO-3G}         & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{ucc-pVDZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{ucc-pVTZ}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVDZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVTZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{uaug-cc-pVQZ}    & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{LuSTO-3G}        & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lucc-pVDZ}       & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Lucc-pVTZ}       & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0          &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVDZ}   & -2.400      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -4.014      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0.484      & -2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVTZ}   & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -6.925  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -6.932      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -6.925     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.386      & 0       & 0.495      &-2.386 \\
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Luaug-cc-pVQZ}   & -2.053      & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.054  & 0          & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & -3.752      & {$\cdots$}  & 0       & -3.752     & 0  \\
                                 & {$\cdots$}  & {$\cdots$}  & -2.352      & 0       & 0.486      &-2.353 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```